Minimum Java version requirement for upgrading to Android 34
We recently updated our Android SDK to target Android 34 from Android 33. I'm on Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1. Consequently, I had to upgrade as below:

targetSdkVersion updated to 34
kotlin_version updated to 1.8.10 (1.5.20)
gradlePluginVersion updated to 8.4.2 (7.4.2)
gradleVersion updated to 8.6 (from 7.5)
JavaVersion updated to 17 (from 11)

One of our customers is now asking if we could compile it with JDK 11 instead of JDK 17. As far as I can see, minimum version requirement for Android 34 is JDK 17 and Gradle 8.6.
They suggest we change our build.gradle as below (currently it's VERSION_17) :
android {
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
}
}

During the upgade to Android 14, I had to change my GRADLE_LOCAL_JAVA_HOME to JDK 17. And when I changed the compileOptions to Version_11 from Version_17, the Gradle does not throw any errors.
Essentially they want to keep using Java 11 for their app. I actually tested the suggested change to the SDK with our sample app and it builds successfully. However, as it's generally very tricky with Gradle and its cache and I'm not sure what this change will lead to any other problems.
Can you please advise if it's ok to change the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility java version to version 11 from version 17?

Cbg_retro , Did you got the solution for the above question ?

I went ahead with the change, but I'm still waiting for our customers to test. So still not confirmed.
